# Why does it take longer to sum integers when they're object attributes?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am learning python after having some java in school back in the day.  If there are 2 lists, one with single digit integers and one with objects with a bunch of attributes, they appear to be a different speed to step through them?  I was under the understanding that the objects are a memory pointer.

Example:

```
int_list = [1] * 1000
obj_list = [CustObject(0,1,2,3)] * 1000

total = 0
for i in int_list:
    total += i
print(total)

total = 0
for o in obj_list:
    total += o.int_variable
print(total)
```

I ran this with some tile objects that have about 20 attributes, one of them being an image.  Obviously the tile list creation takes a lot more time, which is expected.  But stepping through them is slower as seen from the output:

```
print("starting test")

ints = [[1 for i in range(100)] for j in range(80)]
print("created ints")

tiles = [[Tile(i, j, 30, 1) for i in range(100)] for j in range(80)]
print("created tiles")

# step through the ints
start_time = time.perf_counter()
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(ints)):
    for j in range(0, len(ints[i])):
        total += ints[i][j]
end_time = time.perf_counter()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Ints Elapsed time: ", elapsed_time, total)

# step through the Tiles
start_time = time.perf_counter()
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(tiles)):
    for j in range(0, len(tiles[i])):
        total += tiles[i][j].tile_type
end_time = time.perf_counter()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Tiles Elapsed time: ", elapsed_time, total)
```

Output

```
starting test
created ints
created tiles
Ints Elapsed time:  0.0011542000574991107 8000
Tiles Elapsed time:  0.002249700017273426 8000
```

Comment: The actual iteration of your two lists should take exactly the same time, given that they're the same length.  However, `i` is a much simpler expression to evaluate than `o.int_variable`...

Comment: I see a very small difference between the times.

Comment: For reference, what is `.tile_type`? It looks like it's a simple attribute corresponding to the last parameter in the `Tile` constructor, is that right? (i.e. `1` in `Tile(i, j, 30, 1)`)

Comment: there's one more name lookup for `.tile_type` attribute, that's it

Comment: yes, the time is very small in this example, but if I plan on performing iterations through these lists hundreds of times per run, I would like to try to reduce the time by multiplying those out.  Jsut trying to be efficient.

Comment: .tile_type is an integer attribute of the Tile class that is set by the 4th  in that argument list (1 in this case)

Comment: @digitalfoss I mean in my simple recreation, I see a negligible difference. I used a data class to fill in for `Tile` and ran it on my machine.

Comment: To answer the title directly, it doesn't, you're measuring the wrong thing. If I could recommend a better title: "Why does it take longer to sum integers when they're stored in object attributes?" See [ask] if you want tips. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Apart form the title, this is a good first question, keep it up! Good description of the problem, good example, and tidy code :)

Comment: It's worth noting that with such a small sample, performance can vary wildly. I've run it a few times now and even got some results where `Tiles Elapsed time` was slightly faster.

Comment: @wjandrea interesting, I ran it about 20 times and each time the ints[] was always notably faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing `ints[i][j]` needs:

- lookup for `ints` variable
- lookup for `i` & `j` variables
- array boundary check

Accessing `tiles[i][j].tile_type` needs the above plus name lookup for `tile_type`, so it's slower.

Anyway, instead of trying to figure out why all this is slower, you can optimize this code a lot by forgetting about indices. This code:

```
for i in range(0, len(tiles)):
    for j in range(0, len(tiles[i])):
        total += tiles[i][j].tile_type
```

becomes (after directly iterating on the objects, not the indices)

```
for ta in tiles:
    for e in ta:
        total += e.tile_type
```

or even faster probably with `sum` and double flat comprehension:

```
total = sum(e.tile_type for ta in tiles for e in ta)
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  I jsut tried replacing the "total +=" in the loops with "pass" with this explanation and now they do appear to be negligible differences in run times.

Comment: fake? can you elaborate?

Comment: if I want to use ChatGPT I can do it myself. Plus this is banned here as you may know